# JSP onmoveover function with java parameter unable to retrieve at javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Right now, i am trying to pass the value from jsp function with java value to javascript. However, i am not able to get the result that i wanted. Instead of getting the arraylist value for eg 4, i'm getting the value like %=list.get(0)%. May i know what's wrong with my code? Is there any syntax error? Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function getValue(value){//expected result would be from arraylist
    alert("Values: " + value); // %=list.get(0)% as the alert message.

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <% ArrayList list=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("listOfValue"); %> 
    <html:link action="/hello" onmouseover="getValue('<%=list.get(0)%>');" />
    </body>
    </html>
```